# Find distance using lat and long in sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to search any place inside 10 k.m. using lat and long. How can i set limit? Here is my sql query:

```
$this->db->select(", ( 6371  acos( cos( radians(37) )  cos( radians(latitude) )   cos( radians( longtitude )- radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude) ) ) ) AS distance");                         
$this->db->from('table_name'); 
$this->db->order_by('distance');
```

Comment: Have you got any error ?

Comment: $this->db->having('distance < 10');
Assuming your select statement is correct and gives you distance in kms

Comment: Where my formula < 10. You can use a bounding rectangle (well, a square) of 20x20 to quickly filter the results

Comment: Also, see prepared statements

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    $this->db->query('  SELECT  ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) )  cos( radians(latitude) )   cos( radians( longtitude )- radians("'.$lng.'") ) + sin( radians("'.$lat.'") ) * sin( radians( latitude) ) ) ) AS distance 
                        FROM table_name
                        HAVING distance < 10
                        ORDER BY distance ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
$this->db->select(", ( 6371  acos( cos( radians(37) )  cos( radians(latitude) )   cos( radians( longtitude )- radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude) ) ) ) AS distance");                         
$this->db->from('table_name'); 
$this->db->having('distance<',10)
$this->db->order_by('distance');
```

Comment: still i am not getting result in kms.

Comment: what you mean by not getting in Kms? are you getting any results or error?

Comment: i am getting result, but getting wrong result, actuly with above query i getting some records with distance field, and in distance filed i getting value like "2181". and your query fetching result with this field. means if i using " distance<10" then nothing result displaying and if i using "distance<2181" then some result displaying.


but i want to search result in kms or miles.

Comment: did you changed the value 37 with the latitude value or its your default latitude?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'select *,(((acos(sin(('.$lat.'*pi()/180)) * 
            sin((loc_LAT_centroid*pi()/180))+cos(('.$lat.'*pi()/180)) * 
            cos((loc_LAT_centroid*pi()/180)) * cos((('.$lang.'-loc_LONG_centroid)* 
            pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515
        ) AS distance from table_name order by distance';

$lat = latitude of your current location
$lang = longitude of your current location

loc_LAT_centroid = field name of your table where you store the latitude of the places.
loc_LONG_centroid = field name of your table where you store the longitude of the places.
```